# Back-up script via bash -- issues with file paths?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to run a back-up bash script in via Plesk scheduled tasks on a CentOS GoDaddy Managed Dedicated Server. I'm having a frustrating amount of trouble with this (made worse by the fact that it *was* working and then stopped...).

What I want to happen: I want an entire back-up of the directory I'm specifying to back-up, placed into the "backups" directory.

**The script I am using:** https://github.com/etiennerached/godaddy-backup-script

**I have tried:**

- backupDirectory='backups'
- filesPath='/'
- I have also tried about all the things I can think to try in the filesPath variable. www/vhosts/subscription-name, html/vhosts/subscription-name, /var/html/vhosts/subscription-name/, /var/www/vhosts/subscription-name/, /subscription-name/, ../, html, httpdocs, and more I've forgotten.

**Settings:**

- It's set to run via Plesk Scheduled Tasks. The call to the script is: `/bin/bash backups/backup.sh` and everything but minutes is set to *. Minutes is set to */1.
- The script is `/var/www/vhosts/subscription-name/backups` as backup.sh, set to 777 permissions. The folder it's in is also set to 777 permissions. Both of these things are to make sure it's not the permissions screwing me up.
- There is a second script, `test.sh`. It's in the same directory as `backup.sh` with the same Plesk Scheduled Tasks settings and the same permissions. It's dutifully writing to a text file every minute as directed.

I thought the script executes in the home directory of my subscription, so I don't really understand why '/' and 'backups' aren't working. But if it executes in the root directory of my server, shouldn't one of the complete path calls work?

Comment: Line 153: why `cd $HOME/$filesPath`? Why not `cd $filesPath`, with `$filesPath` being an absolute path (like `/var/www/html` and not `www/html`).

Comment: Tried removing $HOME/ in all instances where it appeared, replacing $filesPath and $backupDirectory with /var/www/vhosts/subscription-name/, varying (tried with starting, trailing slashes, one or the other, both, also tried with /html/ instead of /www/). No dice.

Comment: Not sure this is an answer so I'm commenting. I did **not** get the linked script working. This [on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/474561/why-does-tar-xvfz-fail-but-tar-xvfz-work) helped get a second script working. On the second script I changed `tar -zcvf $filesname .` to `tar czvf` and now the second script is working. This one also uses `tar -zcvf` so maybe removing the dash would have worked here as well. Thanks for the assistance: sorry I can't offer upvotes (too new).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to backup the *directory you specify* this should work:

Place this script into the directory you want to backup:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Check if "backups" exists / if not create folder
if [ ! -d "backups" ]
then
mkdir backups
fi

#Begin Backup
#Choose if you want to use gzip or just tar

#TAR with gzip
#tar -cvfz  --exclude=backups --exclude=${BASH_SOURCE[0]} backups/backup.tar.gz .

#TAR without gzip
#tar -cvf  --exclude=backups --exclude=${BASH_SOURCE[0]} backups/backup.tar.gz .

#NOTE: We exclude "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" because that's the name of our script,
#      so you can rename it to whatever you like
exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried this by sticking backup.sh in the home directory of the subscription and uncommenting both styles of backup, one at a time. No dice.